# How to know a file type programmatically?

Tags: java

I work with 3 different types of file (XML, CSV and JSON) and I don't know which one I work at some point. I tried with some code, say,

```
File file = new File("src/main/java/data" + "/molecules.xml");
final MimetypesFileTypeMap fileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
System.out.println(fileTypeMap.getContentType(file.getName()));
```

and it returns `application/octet-stream`and it goes same for `.csv` and the `.json` file as well. How do I get the correct file type ?

Comment: You either examine the file [name endings](https://tika.apache.org/1.14/api/org/apache/tika/detect/NameDetector.html), or you try to detect the type by file content (for example, [Apache Tika](https://tika.apache.org/1.14/detection.html)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct MIME type will only show up if [`MimetypesFileTypeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) can match the file type using one of these resources:

> 1. Programmatically added entries to the MimetypesFileTypeMap instance.
> 2. The file `.mime.types` in the user's home directory.
> 3. The file `<java.home>/lib/mime.types`.
> 4. The file or resources named `META-INF/mime.types`.
> 5. The file or resource named `META-INF/mimetypes.default` (usually found only in the activation.jar
>      file).

The quickest solution is to use option #1 via [`addMimeTypes`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html#addMimeTypes-java.lang.String-):

```
final MimetypesFileTypeMap fileTypeMap = new MimetypesFileTypeMap();
fileTypeMap.addMimeTypes("text/csv csv CSV");
fileTypeMap.addMimeTypes("application/json json JSON");
fileTypeMap.addMimeTypes("application/xml xml XML");
```